# Sum of fields values is not returning the correct value after saving a object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass the result from a sum aggregation function to another object after saving it. However, every time I change the value save the object, the sum aggregation queryset result is not correct. How do I properly do this?

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    total = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)


class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(Player, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # new_total value does not get updated. 
        new_total = Player.objects.filter(team=self.team).aggregate(Sum('score')).get('score__sum')
        Team.objects.filter(id=self.team.id).update(total=new_total)
        print(new_total) # if I'm saving a new value of 15, this will still print 10


@receiver(post_save, sender=Player)
def sum(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # new_total_attempt_two value does not get updated either. 
    new_total_attempt_two = sender.objects.filter(squad=instance.squad).aggregate(Sum('score')).get('score__sum')
    print(new_total_attempt_two)  # if I'm saving a new value of 15, this will still print 10
```

If I have an existing object with score 10 and change it to 15, I expect the total on Team model to get updated to 15 but it is still 10.

I'm using python 3.6, django 2.1.7.
I also tried using post_save signals but had no success either.

Comment: How are you verifying that the total is not updated? Note, the signal does not seem to save the score_sum anywhere, in any case.

Comment: Also note, you're probably better off calculating the aggregate whenever you need it for display, rather than storing it separately.

Comment: @DanielRoseman by printing new_score and new_total_attempt_two

Comment: @DanielRoseman I need that value stored for further purposes

Comment: Printing them where? Please show the whole code and output.

Comment: Just updated my answer. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
self.team.total = new_total
self.team.save()
```

Comment: Just tried that and did now work. It strangely saves the previous result from the sum aggregate function. For example, if I change one player.score to 15 and save it, team.score is still 10. If I change  player.score again to X, now team.score is 15.  @AjayShelar

Comment: Use clean method instead of save